# undefined symbol: PyExc_ImportError when embedding Python in C

Tags: c, module, makefile, python-2.7, importerror

I'm developing a C shared library that makes a call to a python script.
When I run the application I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/galaxy-es/lib/galaxy/earthsystem/gridftp_security/gridftp_acl_plugin.py", line 2, in <module>
    import galaxy.eggs
  File "/home/ubuntu/galaxy-es/lib/galaxy/eggs/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import os, sys, shutil, glob, urllib, urllib2, ConfigParser, HTMLParser, zipimport, zipfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import io
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_ImportError
```

If I try to import the module io from console works fine instead:

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import galaxy.eggs
>>>
```

During the compilation of library I've used this compiler option as suggest here :
[Embedding python in C, undefined symbol: PyExc_ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767057/embedding-python-in-c-undefined-symbol-pyexc-importerror)
In addition I've added also the compiler options obtained from 
python-config --includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags

Here you can find the log of makefile of library http://pastebin.com/348rhBjM

Thanks a lot, any help will be apreciated.

Comment: The command should be this : http://pastebin.com/jSqSnBj5, Here instead http://pastebin.com/348rhBjM you can find the whole make log.

Comment: You have lots of warning that you really should check into! At a quick glance the most serious seems to be this: `globus_gfs_acl_vm.c:260:33: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘snprintf’ makes integer from pointer without a cast`. While probably unrelated to your problem, you should _really_ try to fix as many warnings a possible!

Comment: @rdil2503: Please mark an answer, preferably Trevor's, as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

[@user1515248 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11847653/52074) is a link-only solution which are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/147407). i am writing this answer to expand on the links he gave and provide a more fleshed out answer (that also backs up the link he gave).

The link, https://mail.python.org/pipermail/new-bugs-announce/2008-November/003322.html, says:

> I have been given the following workaround: in mylib.c, before
>   `PyInitialize()` I can call `dlopen("libpython2.5.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL)`;
>
> This works, but I believe that lib-dynload/*.so should depend on
>   libpython2.5.so.1 so this hack should not be necessary.
>
> I am using Ubuntu 8.04 with Python version 2.5.2-2ubuntu4.1.

All I had to do was add a single line of code:

```
// new line of code
void*const libpython_handle = dlopen("libpython2.6.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);

PyInitialize();
```

p.s.
I am on CentOS-6.

p.p.s.
My `PyInitialize()` is wrapped in a class and so `dlopen()`/`PyInitialize()` is done in the constructor and `dlclose()`/`PyFinalize()` is done in the destructor.

Comment: Dont forget to say that it must be included #include <dlfcn.h> to support dlopen and RTLD_LAZY

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution. Maybe can be useful for someone else.
It's a bug of python as written here http://mail.python.org/pipermail/new-bugs-announce/2008-November/003322.html
I've used the solution posted here http://www.cilogon.org/gsi-c-authz

Comment: the first link, http://mail.python.org/pipermail/new-bugs-announce/2008-November/003322.html, provides a concise and easy to understand problem statement and solution.

Comment: the second link, http://www.cilogon.org/gsi-c-authz, is long and meandering and is written for one specific application *and i could not find anything that looked like a generic solution*. **definitely go with the first link**

Answer (score 0):

I use such workaround: explicit linking of plugins from lib-dynload directory (it's simply, then explicit dlopen in code). Example with datetime.so:

cmake:

```
SET ( CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so" )
```

or just add /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so as linker parameter to
gcc in command line:

```
g++ -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o -lbar -lzab /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
```