# import Error while importing python nltk module in node.js using "python-node" module

Tags: python, node.js, datetime, python-2.7, nltk

I am trying to import python natural language processing toolkit nltk in node.js using node-python mentioned here: https://npmjs.org/package/node-python

The commands i am giving are similar as mentioned on the npm module site:

```
var python = require('node-python');
var os = python.import('os');
```

i am getting the following error:

```
Error: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_SystemError
    at repl:1:25
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:109:21)
    at rli.on.self.bufferedCmd (repl.js:258:20)
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:116:5)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:248:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:200:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:518:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:736:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:97:10)
```

I am using python2.7.2
After much search i found that this is a known bug in python2.7 and found a similar problem when importing from `C` here is the what i found:
[similar error found while importing python datetime module from `C`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842920/undefined-symbol-pyexc-importerror-when-embedding-python-in-c)

The problem seems to be in the datetime.so module, i was thinking of getting the updated version of the datetime module and compiling it separately to make it work. I am still looking for that module and comple instructions. I would really appreciate If anyone has a better suggestion to resolve this or even help me locate the place to find this datetime module and its compile instructions. I really don't want to compile the whole python to make it work.

Comment: Did you try updating the datetime module?  I would like to use NLTK via node as well.

Comment: No, apparently you have to manually compile python to make it work, and i was not ready for that, a lot of other stuff is using my current python installation. I ended up making a small web service in python itself and used it with nodejs http module. here is the final thing: http://conterface.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a lot less pain than recompiling python std libs.  I also considered using a AMQP layer (rabbitMQ, etc..) to connect things  like NLTK or even StanfordNLP.   Your app looks like it works well.

Comment: I guess if you are building a high load system you may want to do that. Thanks for trying out the app.