# Python: ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_Replace

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to build a triviol Python script that will grab data from URL and save it onto the server. Concider the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pprint
import json
import urllib2

def getUSGS_json():
    print "Fetch data from URL"

    fileName = 'data/usgsEarthquacks_12Hrs.json'
    url = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson'
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

    if data:
        try:
            with open(fileName) as jsonGetData:
                filePut = open(fileName, 'w+')
                #add data
                filePut.write(data)
                filePut.close()

                j = json.load(jsonGetData)
                print j
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            raise
        else:
            pass
        finally:
            pass
    #end if
#end getUSGS_json

getUSGS_json()
```

Upon running the script I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geoJsonFetch.py", line 4, in <module>
    import urllib2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 79, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_Replace
```

I have looked around on SO and found similar errors like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842920/undefined-symbol-pyexc-importerror-when-embedding-python-in-c), but they do not seem to get at the heart of why some people are able to get this code to run and I am not. They all seem to be dealing with issues concerning developing in C and using Python to access that C module.

Is it the Ubuntu version, Python version??

Thank you.

Comment: should you not be using `data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()`?

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple installations of Python that are stomping on each other.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have (at least) two different versions of Python installed and you're mixing their files. Make sure that `$PYTHONPATH`, `$PYTHONHOME` and `sys.path` only contain folders for a single Python installation. In your case, one installation is in `/usr/local` and the other is probably in `/usr`.

Also, you can try installing `virtualenvwrapper` and setting up separate python environment to alleviate any conflicts you might be having. [Here](http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial-part-2/) is a tutorial for installing and using virtualenv.

Comment: How does one do that exactly? Can you elaborate a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: To help further, I need to know which versions of Python you have installed, how you installed them and how you start your application. Please edit your question to give me this info.

Comment: No need. The Virtualenv solution worked for me and seems to be a better way of doing things moving forward anyway. Would love a thumbs up if you think the question might benefit others. Cheers.