# Unable to import python packages in Ubuntu (ImportError : undefined symbol)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, tensorflow

I recently installed python on my Ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded tensorflow by `pip`.
When I tried to `import tensorflow` it said `ImportError:No module named tensorflow`.
Then I edited `PYTHONPATH` by adding `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. Now when I try to import, it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUnicodeEscapeString
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383054/python-importerror-usr-local-lib-python2-7-lib-dynload-io-so-undefined-symb) that 2 versions of python causes the conflict, but that didn't help. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: run `pip` from your install of python (in `scripts` subdirectory) to be sure you update the wanted version of python

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to install packages if you have more than one python installed is:

```
path_to_your_python_executable -m pip install package_name
```

This way, you can make sure that you have installed package for proper python.

And don't forget about sudo ;)

Comment: Hello, thankyou for assistance but it didn't work :(